# moreverb conflict with spverbatim, texlive 2016

Tags: packages, verbatim, incompatibility

I always get package conflicts ;) as I have a large common input file, where I load many packages at once (too lazy to type only the ones I really need each time for each file as I have 1,000's of Latex files).

I just found out that if package `\usepackage{moreverb}` and `\usepackage{spverbatim}` are loaded in same file, an error happens. I looked at the https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spverbatim and did not notice this mentioned there. So here is a MWE showing the problem

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{spverbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{spverbatim}
{{y[x] -> C[1] + Integrate[a*f[K[1]], {K[1], 1, x}]}}
\end{spverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex foo.tex`

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 2
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moreverb/moreverb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/spverbatim/spverbatim.sty)
(./foo.aux)

! LaTeX Error: \begin{spverbatim} on input line 7 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \end{document}
```

Removing the `\usepackage{moreverb}` now it compiles OK.

Is this known issue? Workaround is to remove the `moreverb` but thought to ask, in case this is not known, or in case this is not supposed to happen and may be there is a bug somewhere.

Tex 2016 on Linux.

Comment: loading packages that you don't need is just a really bad idea.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree. But on the other hand, having to retype 10-20 lines each time in each file, is a pain and too slow. Also, packages should not really conflict with each others.

Comment: Why exactly should packages not conflict with each other? It is inevitable that you have lots of conflicts, given that there are thousands of packages, written by hundreds of people of varying LaTeX skills and with varying knowledge about other packages. As a package author it is impossible to be aware of all potential interactions with all other packages. Moreover, packages with similar purpose are bound to have conflicts. If you don't mind spending hours on tracking down conflcts, then you can save the minute required to select the packages actually needed.

Comment: Of course packages will conflict, especially as here where they are modifying the same internals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two packages are not compatible, `moreverb` redefined `\verbatim` (adding an extra layer of grouping) which is inconsistent with the redefinitions made by `spverbatim`.

Of course if there is a specific use case requiring the functionality of both packages then something could be written, but if as seems likely it is just the natural result of loading multiple packages, then it would be better to simply load one or the other than have to maintain a third variant package.